# flex direction "row" inside a flexbox with flex-direction "column"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a navbar using flexbox. In my code I have the actual navbar wrapped with flex- direction:"row" to align the logo and the button.
Now I want to have the nav-inner (the beige div) under the navbar (that should be 100vw wide), but actually it sits next to the navbar.
I have tried to change the flex-direction to "column" inside my nav-menu div, but the Hamburger button goes out of the screen. Am I doing something wrong?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* defaults */
.safe-view {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hamburger {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

/**/
/* navbar */
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  height: 100px;
}

.nav-menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  /*flex-direction:column;*/
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}


.nav-inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

/**/
```

```html
<div class="safe-view">
        <div class="nav-menu">
            <div class="navbar">
                <h1>logo</h1>
                    <button class="hamburger"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS box-model issue. You need to add [box-sizing: border-box](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/). This will ensure that padding is included in calculation of the width.

```
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;  
}
```

By default box-sizing is set to `content-box`. This will only care about the element content and shift padding and border outside of the element. That is why you saw the button push out to the right! [This](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/) can also help you to understand further.

Also, `flex-direction` for .`nav-menu` needs to be set to `column` in order to position `.nav-inner` below.

Heres an alternative. I removed padding and just used `calc()` function to create padding. But always include `box-sizing:border-box` in your CSS :)

```css
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;  
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.safe-view {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: calc(100vw - 60px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  height: 100px;
}

.nav-menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav-inner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
```

```html
<div class="safe-view">
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <div class="navbar">
      <h1 class="logo">logo</h1>
      <button class="hamburger">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```